# gridview section header

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is there a way to create section headers in a Gridview? Or to achive a similar result with some other control?

I've had a couple of cases now where I've wanted the screen to look like this ... let me see if I can give the idea with some ASCII art ...

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| Office          | Manager   | Sales     |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Eastern Region                          |
+-----------------------------------------+
| New York        | Hamilton  | 1,400,000 |
| Boston          | Adams     | 1,150,000 |
| Philadelphia    | Franklin  |   980,000 |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Southern Region                         |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Atlanta         | Marion    |   840,000 |
| Charlottesville | Jefferson |   920,000 |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Western Region                          |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Dodge City  | Earp          |   450,000 |
| Kansas City | Oakley        |   380,000 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

That is, when some key field changes, I want a header row over the new section, that has a different format from the detail rows.

Is there any way to do this with a GridView or some other control?

So far I've done it by generating some or all of the HTML tags with code and building a big string mixing tags and data. This works but it's awkward, difficult to read, and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Am I correct to say you want childgrid sitting inside the parent grid

Comment: @HatSoft Not exactly. I don't want the header in one column and the child list in another column: I want the header above the child. This may seem like a technicality but ine one case, the user has some specific layout requirements that I'm trying to meet, and in another case, the header is long and putting it to the left uses up a lot of screen space and forces the user to constantly scroll left and right to see the data, which is annoying. Also I have a case where the header includes totals, which should line up with the data that they total, not be separate columns to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table control of ASP.NET and manipulated the data as you want to display.